# How to decrement items in array Incrementally based on the given quantity in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this sample array of objects

```
   mangoes:[
      { quantity:5},
      { quantity:8},
      { quantity:13},
      { quantity:4}
    ]
```

When I remove x mangoes, that x should be subtracted from the first element in the array, and if that x exceed the first element then it should reduce the remained quantity in the second item in the array...and so forth.

This is to say, I need the quantity to be reduced starting from the first one in the array down to the second if it exceed, to the third etc..

For example, If I buy 2 mangoes, It should minus 2 in the first array element and the resulting mangoes array should be

```
   mangoes:[
      { quantity:3},
      { quantity:8},
      { quantity:13},
      { quantity:4}
    ]
```

On the other hand, If I would have bought 7 mangoes, it should reduce all 5 from first array element and then remove 2 mangoes from the second element...and hence the final array would be like this below

```
   mangoes:[
      { quantity:0},
      { quantity:6},
      { quantity:13},
      { quantity:4}
    ]
```

By Using Javascript, how can I achieve this?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried like this below, It works only for the first element(case) when the x is less, but for other case it doesn't work;

```
var x = 2
var done = false

mangoes.forEach(function (item,i) {

  if(mangoes[i].quantity>=x && !done){
    item.quantity = mangoes[i].quantity - x
    done = true
  }

})
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: @HassanImam I have updated my question to show the code that i have tried... please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a `closure` inside map and generate the desired result.

```js
var mangoes=[ { quantity:5},{ quantity:8},{ quantity:13},{ quantity:4}];
var toReduce = 5;

var result = mangoes.map((num=>({quantity})=>(r = Math.min(quantity,num),num=num-r,({quantity:quantity-r})))(toReduce));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution works with all types of arrays I have tested, even with mongodb arrays, and it is simple with less code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const takeMangoes = (num, from) => from.map(x => {
  const take = Math.min(x.quantity, num);
  num -= take;
  // Original way, keep all properties, don't mutate original
  //return {...x, quantity: x.quantity - take};
  
  // Pick from below:

  // New way 1, mutate original in place
  x.quantity = x.quantity - take;
  return x;
  // New way 2, limit to OWN properties
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x).reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = x[c];
    if (c === 'quantity') {
      a[c] -= take;
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
}).filter(x => x.quantity > 0);

console.log(takeMangoes(2, [
  {quantity: 5},
  {quantity: 8},
  {quantity: 13},
  {quantity: 4},
]));

console.log('------------------------');

console.log(takeMangoes(7, [
  {quantity: 5},
  {quantity: 8},
  {quantity: 13},
  {quantity: 4},
]));
```

Comment: I have tried it on my own and it works.. It returns {quantity:0} when the item is finished(which is okay to me). What if I don't want {quantity:0} to appear in the output, how do I condition it?

Comment: @Amani I've edited the answer to include that additional removal of non-positive qtys.

Comment: @Chase My actual mangoes array is coming from mongodb, and when I pass it in the function above, suprisingly it doesn't work. It generates a very long array with '__parentArray' thing. Why is that and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with an array? Is maybe a Cursor object?

Comment: @Chase Its an array `[
    {
        "quantity": 5,
        "buyPrice": {
            "$numberDecimal": "800"
        },
        "_id": "5ed6055cec60724125acd43f"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 5,
        "buyPrice": {
            "$numberDecimal": "700"
        },
        "_id": "5ed60566ec60724125acd441"
    }
]`

Comment: Well as you can see all the stuff that comes out was already part of it going in. In any case, I've edited the answer to show two additional ways you might be interested in. One mutates the incoming objects in-place. The second limits the properties copied to the properties that belong directly to the objects in your array but does not mutate the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `forEach` this way. But I wouldn't recommend it because even if a quantity is found to be greater than the value to be deducted, it will still loop through the whole item list as you can't break out of a `forEach` loop

```js
  var mangoes = [
      { quantity:0},
      { quantity:6},
      { quantity:13},
      { quantity:4}
    ];

var x = 2
var done = false

mangoes.forEach(function (item,i) {

 if(item.quantity< x){
   item.quantity = 0;
   x = x- item.quantity; 
  }else{
   item.quantity = item.quantity-x;
   x=0;
  }

});
console.log(mangoes)
```

However, I would recommend using `for..of..loop` so that you could conditionally break out of the loop, i.e if the quantity is found to be greater than the ones to be deducted, just deduct and break out of the loop. There's no need of further iteration.

```js
  var mangoes = [
      { quantity:5},
      { quantity:6},
      { quantity:13},
      { quantity:4}
    ];

var x = 1
var done = false

for(let i of mangoes){
  if(i.quantity >= x){
    i.quantity  = i.quantity -x;
    x = x - i.quantity;
    break;
  }else{
    x = x - i.quantity;
    i.quantity = 0;
  }
}

console.log(mangoes)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 8;

const newMangoes = mangoes.map((mango) => {
    if (!x) return mango;
    if (x <= mango.quantity) {
        newMango =  {quantity: mango.quantity - x};
        x = 0;
        return newMango;
    } else {
        x = x - mango.quantity;
        return {quantity: 0};
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getMangoes = function(requested){
  var remaining = requested;
  var supplied = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < mangoes.length() && supplied < requested; i++){
    if(mangoes[i].quantity >= remaining){
      mangoes[i].quantity -= remaining;
      supplied += remaining;
    }
    else {
      remaining -= mangoes[i].quantity;
      supplied += mangoes[i].quantity;
    }
  }
  return(supplied);
};

var mangoesIWant = 13;
var mangoesIGot = getMangoes(mangoesIWant);
```